# How can I check in Gradle that a project has a task with a given name?

Tags: gradle

I need to find out in a gradle build script if an arbitrary project (root or any of its sub-projects) has a task with a given name.

Is there a built-in API for this?

Comment: May I ask what you want to achieve? There may be multiple ways to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition like the below, to check if a task exists:

```
if (tasks.findByPath('someTask')) {
    // do something
}
```